# Register a user via Facebook login (no username/password specified)

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

The Parse documentation provides instructions on associating a Facebook account with a registered ParseUser.

To register a ParseUser, the user needs to pick a username, password and provide an email.

I am creating a mobile game where I will be using Parse to store data about game sessions and I will be using Facebook to allow users to "Challenge" their Facebook friends to initiate these challenges.

For this reason, I would like to let my users "register" by logging in to my game with their Facebook account. I do not need them to pick a username and password.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Parse user after you logged in via Facebook and there will be no need to provide any username, password or email. Use the Facebook Unity SDK to log in your user first as shown here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples#login

Then create a Parse user associated with that Facebook user using the Parse ParseFacebookUtils by calling `LogInAsync()` method:

```
Task<ParseUser> logInTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync(userId, accessToken, tokenExpiration);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thrown off by reading everywhere that the username/password was 'required'.